# Can't get images to load from json using React

Tags: json, reactjs

newbie StackOverFlow member and newbie coder here.  Wondering if I could get some help on a small project I am working on.  I'm trying to learn React and am trying to get images I've saved to JSON under 'favorites' to load on my 'favorites' page of my project. It might just be a syntax error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Let me know if you need more details. I'm very new to this. Thank you~

https://github.com/ebventurino/Palette/tree/master/src/Favorites

Comment: What specific error(s) are you getting? Also I don't understand your component setup, `Favorites` renders a `SingleFavorite`, which renders an array of `Favorites`. I can't see `Favorite` even getting rendered anywhere. The setup should just be something like a `FavoritesList` component, which fetches the favourites and then renders a `Favorite` component per response data item.

Comment: No errors, just a blank page. Thanks for the feedback, I will rearrange so the files are easier to read.